# Redirect wp-login to custom login and remember referring page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to replace the default wp-login with my custom login form. The hard part is to make the redirect to referring page work.

I was able to find various snippets to do the following

1. redirect wp-login to custom page
2. capture referring page and redirect after successful login
3. logged-in user is redirected to homepage when they try to access the login page

My problem is that I'm using an LMS plugin the redirects a non-loggedin user to wp-login. So this is what happens

1. User opens page A
2. Page A requires login and so it redirects user to wp-login
3. my code then redirects the user to my custom login page
4. after successful login, the user is redirected not to page A, but to the homepage. (since the last referrer is wp-login)

I understand why and I'm trying to look for a solution that will send the user back to page A (for the above use-case).

Appeciate any guidance.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Does the redirect plugin offer any filters in the relevant locations, that you could hook into?

Comment: In step 2, does it append the URL to redirect back to as a GET parameter? Maybe you can grab it from there, in step 3?